# How to install VeraCrypt onto USB

Tags: usb, software-installation, veracrypt

I know how to encrypt a file and move it onto a USB with VeraCrypt(VC) however, I want to install VC on my USB so I don't have to install VC on every computer I use. All the instructions I have found for doing this are for windows. Any help would be appreciated